# I have some issues with multiple checkbox in React Js

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

```js
<ul>
    {mobileNetworks
    ? mobileNetworks.map((network) => (
        <li>
            <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={network.service_provider_id}
            checked={
                filters.service_provider_id.includes(
                network.service_provider_id
                )
                ? true
                : false
            }
            name="service_provider_id"
            onChange={(e) => handleFilters(e)}
            />
            <label className="checkbox" htmlFor="Option2">
            {network.name} <span>({network.count})</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        ))
    : ""}
</ul>
```

```js
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    service_provider_id: [5],
    offer: [],
    monthly_cost: [],
    data: [],
    minute: [],
    contract: [],
    rating: "",
  });
  const handleFilters = (e) => {
    console.log("hhh");
    var new_list = [];
    const { name, value } = e;
    console.log(name, value);
    if (filters.name.includes(value)) {
      new_list = filters.service_provider_id.filter(
        (present_id) => present_id != value
      );
    } else {
      new_list = filters.service_provider_id.push(value);
    }
    setFilters({
      ...filters,
      service_provider_id: new_list,
    });
  };
```

This is my code..Mobile networks is coming from an api..I am not able to check or uncheck any checkboxes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv6pq.png)

I tried this but no use https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-work-with-multiple-checkboxes-in-react/

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console?

Comment: No Tim..Nothing Happens when i click on the checkboxes

Comment: Is it possible to provide the mobileNetworks variable json?

Comment: I got the solution..It was dumb the label attribute htmlFor didnt match the id...Did not know it could stop the whole process..Anyways Thank you Everyone

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution..It was dumb the label attribute htmlFor didnt match the id of the checkbox...Did not know it could stop me from checking and unchecking checkboxes..Anyways Thank you Everyone